# I want to resize the font-size, while resizing the the table elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

While increasing height and width of the table the font-size should also be increased and vice versa.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>jQuery UI Resizable - Default functionality</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes  
    /smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <style>
            #resizable {
                width: 150px;
                height: 150px;
                padding: 0.5em;
            }
            #resizable h3 {
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#resizable").resizable();
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="ui-widget-content">
            <table id="resizable">
                <tr>
                    <th>I want to resize this font-size, directly proportionally while resizing this table</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/frozentoor/nguk1tfu/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Maybe you like this approach**

http://jsfiddle.net/nguk1tfu/11/

```
$(function() {
  $( "#resizable" ).resizable();
  old_width = $( "#resizable" ).width();
  old_height = $( "#resizable" ).height();

  $( "#resizable" ).resize(function(){
       current_widht = $( "#resizable" ).width();
       current_height = $( "#resizable" ).height();
      // this shoud the de index for font decrease or increase
      r = (current_widht/old_width) * (current_height/old_height); 
   if( r >= 1)
   {

      r = r*2; // you can change this
      $( "#resizable" ).css('font-size', 11 + r);
   }
   else
   {
       r = r*2;
      $( "#resizable" ).css('font-size', 11 - r);
   }
   });

 });
```

Answer (score 3):

Then you can use font-size in viewport unit for example:

```
p{
  font-size: 1vw;
}
```

Look for different viewport unit:

```
1vw = 1% of viewport width
1vh = 1% of viewport height
1vmin = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is smaller
1vmax = 1vw or 1vh, whichever is larger
```

[image]

[See more on css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Comment: @ Bhojendra Nepal, its not working. i tried on fiddle.